# [C++]Memory error thrown at destructor that wasn't there before this code. Trying to make a new dynamic array and populate it

Tags: c++, data-structures, priority-queue

I am working on a lab dealing with queues, which I don't think is entirely relevant. My task is to create a "priority queue" and the best way I could think of to do it is as follows

```
void IntQueue::enqueue(int num,int priorityOfEntry)
{   
    if (isFull())
        cout << "The queue is full.\n";
    else
    {   
        // Calculate the new rear position
        //insert correct lab code here haha
        if (priorityOfEntry == 1)
        {   
            rear = (rear + 1) % queueSize;
            queueArray[rear] = num;
            queueSize++;
        }   
        else if (priorityOfEntry == 2)
        {   

            queueSize++;

            int* newArray = new int[queueSize];
            newArray[0] = num;

            for(int counter = 0;counter< queueSize; counter++)
            {   
                newArray[counter+1] = queueArray[counter];
            }   

            queueArray = newArray;

            delete [] newArray;

        }   
        else cout << "invalid priority" << endl;

        // Insert new item


        // Update item count
        numItems++;


    }   
}
```

I only have 2 priority levels, 1 and 2, that I explain in the main program. when they all have equal priority it of course works fine, but when I bump on up in priority it throws an error at my destructor.

I really don't think this is the right way to approach this lab, but It seems to work.. at least if I can actually get this memory error fixed.
I figure the only problem could be in that I change the address of what the destructor thinks it will delete.. but I thought pointers would already kind of account for that.
I understand I need to learn to debug my own programs. I really do. but sometimes I just stare at code and there is nothing but a brick wall there. Guess that's what a nudge in the right direction is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`queueArray` is a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) after this:

```
  queueArray = newArray; // Both 'queueArray' and 'newArray' point to
                         // the same memory after this assignment. 
  delete [] newArray;
```

as the memory that `queueArray` is pointing to has been `delete`d. Any attempt to access or destroy `queueArray` is accessing memory that has already been destroyed. The correct order is:

```
delete[] queueArray;
queueArray = newArray;
```

Additionally, there is a potential out-of-bounds access in the `for` loop that performs the copying:

```
for(int counter = 0;counter< queueSize; counter++)
{
    // When 'counter == queueSize - 1'
    // 'newArray[counter + 1]' is one past the end.
    newArray[counter+1] = queueArray[counter];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had answered my own question just as I saw these answers come in. I think i'm working past the point of actual productivity. Luckily I got it though, and I was even fortunate enough to figure it out on my own. Although you reinforced that I was right, which is awesome. And, had i not figured it out, i could've used the remediation.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
queueArray = newArray; // queueArray and newArray point to the same place
delete [] newArray;    // that place gets delete[]ed
```

you are making `queueArray` point to the same place as `newArray`, but then you are deleting the array that lies in that location. So `queueArray` is left pointing to memory you have given back to the OS, i.e it is now a *dangling pointer*.

You need to `delete queueArray[]` first, then assign `newArray` to it.

Comment: This marks the first time I've actually done something in my code that exactly matches what someone suggested before they suggested it. I actually forgot to mention it when i answered my own question though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it, I don't know why I thought I needed to add another member of the array when the priority switched, I think i'm just tired.

So that was the extra array member
and i think that was the only other problem